# Question on Specular Reflection

Tags: graphics, visualization, computer-vision

Does anybody know why Specular Reflection is defined as
 Reflection = 2 ( Normal . Light ) Normal - Light
where Normal is the normal of the plane and 
Light is the normalize vector from the light source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reflect a vector you need to reverse the component of that vector that lies on a particular axis. For example, to reflect a vector off the x-axis, you could just flip the sign of the y component. Another way to look at that is to multiply the y component by a factor of -1. Yet another way to achieve that goal is to subtract twice the y component from itself. This last variant is what is used in the formula you site.

We want to subtract some multiple of the surface normal from our direction vector. The (Normal.Light) term gives you the component of the light vector that lies along the normal (similar to the y component in the example above). We then need twice that amount (hence the 2) and we want to change the vector in the direction of the normal, so that number needs to be multiplied by the normal. You do seem to have swapped the terms on around the minus.

Comment: thanks for your reply @phkahler, the formula is actually given in the here @ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specular_reflection. I guess should be correct. 
I think i can understand what you want to say. That the vector of the reflection is Normal - Light. However I do not really understand the portion where we need to Dot product the normal and the light. and why the need to multiply by 2.

Comment: He explained it if you read closer.  The dot product is the projection of the light vector onto the normal, and you need twice that in order to get the reflected vector.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment =x but i couldn't really grasp the concept of dot product is the project of light vector onto the normal though..

Answer (score 0):

It is perhaps a consequence of the general reflection described here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(mathematics)

You probably need to know a bit vector geometry or linear algebra to understand why though.